# Processing 3 - Displaying objects from ArrayList

Tags: oop, object, arraylist, processing

I want to create objects with left mouse click and remove them one by one with right click. I could solve my previous problems about adding, storing and removing objects by looking at older questions but I want the objects to appear exactly where the users clicks and I could not find the solution to display each object with the correct coordinates. Currently, the first object is displayed at (0, 0) and I cannot even see the rest but I can see from the console that the objects are successfully created. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList dots;

void setup() {
 size(500, 500);
 background(255);
 dots = new ArrayList();
 colorMode(HSB);
 strokeWeight(2);
}

void mousePressed() {
 if(mouseButton==LEFT) {
   dots.add(new Dot(mouseX, mouseY));
   Dot temp1 = (Dot)dots.get(dots.size()-1);
   temp1.create(dotX, dotY);
 }
 if(mouseButton==RIGHT && dots.size()>0) {
   dots.remove(dots.size()-1);
 }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i++) {
    Dot temp2 = (Dot)dots.get(i);
    temp2.display(coord[0], coord[1]);
  }
  println("Object count: " + dots.size());
}

int dotX;
int dotY;
int[] coord = {dotX, dotY};

class Dot{
  int id;
  Dot(int dotX, int dotY) {
    id = dots.size();
    dotX = mouseX;
    dotY = mouseY;
  }

  int[] create(int dotX, int dotY) {
    int[] coord = {dotX, dotY};
    display(dotX, dotY);
    return coord;
  }

  void display(int dotX, int dotY) {
    float c1 = map(dotX, 0, width, 0, 255);
    noStroke();
    fill(c1, 255, 255);
    ellipse(dotX, dotY, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

I made create() return an array because otherwise it seems like I cannot refer to each object's coordinates while displaying it but I think the main problem is something about it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is caused by having class-level `dotX`, `dotY`, and `coord` variables. That means that all of your `Dot` instances are sharing the same positions. Get rid of those variables.

Instead, you need to use variables **inside the `Dot` class**, that way each `Dot` can have its own position.

Then you have a bunch of extra junk that you need to get rid of. Your `create()` function doesn't seem to do anything useful, and your `display()` function doesn't need to take any arguments, since you'll already have variables inside the `Dot` class that you should be using instead.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Dot>  dots = new ArrayList<Dot>();

void setup() {
 size(500, 500);
 background(255);
}

void mousePressed() {
 if(mouseButton==LEFT) {
   dots.add(new Dot(mouseX, mouseY));

 }
 if(mouseButton==RIGHT && dots.size()>0) {
   dots.remove(dots.size()-1);
 }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for(Dot dot : dots){
    dot.display();
  }
}



class Dot{

  float dotX;
  float dotY;

  int id;
  Dot(int dotX, int dotY) {
    id = dots.size();
    this.dotX = dotX;
    this.dotY = dotY;
  }

  void display() {
    float c1 = map(dotX, 0, width, 0, 255);
    noStroke();
    fill(c1, 255, 255);
    ellipse(dotX, dotY, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Also notice that I added generics to your `ArrayList`.

Instead of this:

```
ArrayList dots = new ArrayList();
```

Do this:

ArrayList dots = new ArrayList();

That `<Dot>` part tells Processing what type of objects your `ArrayList` will hold, so you no longer have to cast, and you can use an enhanced for loop.

Comment: Thank you! Also thanks for pointing the silly mistake I made in the beginning.